# Как связать плагин Dropzone.js с обычной формой обратной связи?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, dropzone

Мне нужно реализовать возможность отправки нескольких изображений + введенные данные (имя, телефон и тд).

Загрузку изображений я реализовал через Dropzone.js (http://www.dropzonejs.com/), но вот как отправить эти файлы - ума не приложу.

```js
  //Моя форма
 $("#form").submit(function() {
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mail.php",
     data: $(this).serialize()
   }).done(function() {
     $(this).find("input").val("");
     alert("Спасибо за заявку! Скоро мы с вами свяжемся.");
     $("#form").trigger("reset");
   });
   return false;
 });

  //Подключение скрипта Dropzone
 var Dropzone = require("dropzone");
 Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
   paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
   maxFilesize: 2, // MB
   accept: function(file, done) {
     if (file.name == "justinbieber.jpg") {
       done("Naha, you don't.");
     } else {
       done();
     }
   }
 };
```

```html
<form method="post" action="mail.php" class="dropzone" id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required />
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" required />
  <br />
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <button>Отправить</button>
</form>
```

Файл mail.php:

```html
<?php

$recepient = "agragregra@ya.ru";
$sitename = "Название сайта";

$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$phone = trim($_POST["phone"]);
$text = trim($_POST["text"]);
$message = "Имя: $name \nТелефон: $phone \nТекст: $text";

$pagetitle = "Новая заявка с сайта \"$sitename\"";
mail($recepient, $pagetitle, $message, "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n From: $recepient");
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту проблему. Кучу времени убил на поиск решения.

Answer (score 0):

Александр, к сожалению, я тоже не особо понимаю PHP, но я вижу, что вы должны дописать свой php скрипт (c js вроде бы все в порядке), в данный момент он не пригоден для работы.
Используйте для работы с почтой [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).
Вам нужно принять файл через глобальный массив `$_FILES[]`, сделать с ними проверки и если они все подходят, отправить эти файлы через метод `addAttachment();`
Используя цикл добавить их всех к письму и уже отправлять.

Я рекомендую прочитать вот эти небольшие статьи, чтоб лучше понимать как работает прием FILES

- [Загрузка на сервер нескольких файлов](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.multiple.php)
- [Загрузка файлов методом
  POST](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)
- А здесь человек показ примеры проверок [Basic File
  Uploading Using PHP](https://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php)

Рекомендую прочитать это все на свежую голову, потому, что статьи простые и понятные.

Я бы сделал примерно так (набрасал код, обычным копированием)
**Форма**

```
<form action="file-upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Файлы:<br />
  <input name="photo[]" type="file" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

**FILE-UPLOAD.php**

```
<?php
 require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    if($_FILES['photo']['name'])
{
    //if no errors...
    if(!$_FILES['photo']['error'])
    {
        //now is the time to modify the future file name and validate the file
      $mail = new PHPMailer;


        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     // Add a recipient
        $mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               // Name is optional
        $mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
        $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
        $mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

        foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $key => value) {
                $mail->addAttachment($value, "photo-{$key}.jpg");    // Optional name

        }
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
        $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

        if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
                echo 'Message has been sent';
        }
    }
}
```